# Oracle OCI Connection Pooling vs Oracle UCP

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, ucp

Oracle offers 4 different JDBC connection pooling mechanisms when the OCI driver is used for JDBC connections:

1. Oracle DataSource
2. Oracle OCI Connection Pooling
3. Oracle UCP (Universal connection pooling -recommended over OracleDataSource)
4. Oracle Database Resident Connection pooling

What are the pros and cons of using Oracle UCP (Universal Connection Pooling) as compared to Oracle OCI Connection Pooling provided by the OCI driver?

Answer (score 1):

I will try adding some details based on the reading I have done so far.

Below are some *distinct* features supported by the different connection pooling mechanisms

1. Oracle UCP (Universal Connection Pooling)

   a. Supports features like Fast Connection Failover (FCF), Runtime connection load balancing and connection affinity.

   b. JMX Support

   c. Support for labelling connections

   d. Support for connection harvesting
2. OCI (Oracle Call Interface) Connection Pooling

   a. Support for session multiplexing.
3. OracleDataSource

   a. Implicit connection cache.

Comment: Can we have both UCP and OCI in one implementation ??

Comment: @Suvasis - Not sure but what would you gain?

Comment: I read blogs and articles on OCI. I am not sure if both are compatible to give better solution or any one is always better than other. How both are different or simillar ?

Comment: I detail above on the features of each connection pools. Anyways I realized neither of them were good (in terms of performance mainly) when compared with other open source connection pools like tomcat-jdbc and bonecp.

Comment: Even I feel we dont have much documentations or examples on configuring  OCI or UCP available on net. I am still looking for. Anyways thanks for the info.